# Debug Enterprise Architect Addin

Tags: debugging, enterprise-architect

I create an addin for `Enterprise Architect`, using `sharpdevelop`, and it works fine.

When I try to debug it I add a break point on the desired location, launch EA, from sharpdevelop I attach to this EA process.

However, the program does not stop at the break point.

The project uses .net 3.5 framework.

Any ideas why can't I debug the addin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to create a config file on your system which specifies the .NET CLR version to be used while debugging the EA.exe process.

Browse to your EA Program Files directory (E.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Sparx Systems\EA)
Create a new file named EA.exe.config
Open the file in Notepad.  Paste the following contents into the file and Save.

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```